# Post data with curl to another server

Tags: php, post, curl

I try to post some data to another server using curl. The problem is that I get nothing on the other server.

Server1:

```
$a = $USER->id;
$b = $USER->username;

 error_reporting(-1);
    $url = 'http://remote_server/a.php';
$data = array(
   'cus' => $a,
   'cust' => $b
);
    $postString = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 2);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postString);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $post = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

and on Server2:

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Of course it doesn't work, it gives array(0) {}.
 So, how I will see the data on the other server?

Comment: Can you echo $postString?

Comment: Yes , I added the 'echo' on Server1 and it gives me:
cus=2&cust=admin. These two are the ID and username of me taken from the db.

Answer (score 0):

To see the actual output of `var_dump($_POST)` in Server2, you must either :

- Server1 side : `echo $post` variable
- Server2 side : write the content of var_dump's result in a file :

  ```
  ob_start();
  var_dump($_POST);
  $output = ob_get_clean();
  $fp = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
  fwrite($fp, $output);
  fclose($fp);
  ```

Comment: thank you for your comment, I have done what you proposed and it did not work: the file created successfully but was empty..

Comment: It cannot be empty. It must at least have `array(0) {}`. Please provide the full code on server2 side.

Comment: Yes you right it was just the array(0). I just used the code you provided nothing more.

Comment: Are you sure that the line `array(0) {}` results of the execution of your script on Server1 ? It seems that you are calling Server2 directly with a GET request...